# Realm - Inner realm list object is not updated after copyToRealmOrUpdate()

Tags: android, realm

I have a Realm object called Message (snippet below) which can also have nested messages of the same type in it:

```
public class Message extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private RealmList<Message> nestedMessages;

}
```

At some point I need to update the list of nested messages e.g if a new nested message is added.

I'm doing that like this:

```
 //newMessage is returned from a request

 realm.beginTransaction();
 RealmList<Message> nestedMessages = initialMessage.getNestedMessages();
 nestedMessages.add(newMessage);  
 initialMessage.setNestedMessages(nestedMessages);
 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(initialMessage);
 realm.commitTransaction();

 //Handle exceptions...
```

But after this the inner object "nestedMessages" is reset and the size is zero.

Is there something I'm missing here? Or does Realm works in a different way for this kind of use case?

NewMessage is the result of this response:

```
protected Response<Message> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    if (isReqSuccessful(response)) {
        try {
            Gson gson = realmGson();
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, Message.class),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
    return Response.error(new VolleyError());
}
```

Comment: What is newMessage? Where do you create it

Comment: New message is a response from a request i make @TimCastelijns

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign a value to newMessage

Comment: @TimCastelijns new message response added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm no realm doesn't work this way. I don't really know how it interacts with lists but try the first solution, if it doesn't work the second one will definitely do:
**1.**

```
 realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmList<Message> nestedMessages = initialMessage.getNestedMessages();
        newMessage = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newMessage);
        nestedMessages.add(newMessage); 
    }
 });
```

**2.**

```
RealmList<Message> nestedMessages = new RealmList<Message>();
RealmList<Message> oldMessages = initialMessage.getNestedMessages();
for(Message message: oldMessages){
    nestedMessages.add(message);
}
newMessage = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newMessage);
nestedMessages.add(newMessage);
initialMessage.setNestedMessages(nestedMessages);
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(initialMessage);
```

Comment: *I don't really know how it interacts with lists* then how can you possibly know your answer will work?

Comment: i've been struggling with realm lists myself, the second answer worked for me. And after i read this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html i thought the first one might work but i didn't try it.

Comment: thanks, the second solution works. Kind of annoying that this isn't straightforward with realm

Comment: In any case, your second solution is incredibly unpractical, even if it works

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you suggest an answer instead of putting down his solution. Thanks for your time too.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast it can be straightforward but need a bit more information for that. Can you answer my question in the comments please

Comment: I know that it's not a good practice that's why i suggested the first answer. It should work according to this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html but I just didn't test it so i added the second one.

Answer (score 3):

If your newMessage is defined by `gson.fromJson(json, Message.class)`, there are only a couple of things you need to do to add it to initialMessage.nestedMessages.

1. Begin transaction
2. Insert newMessage into realm
3. Add it to nestedMessages.
4. Commit transaction

Beginning and committing a transaction (and cancelling in case of failure) is automatically handled by `executeTransaction()`.

Should be as simple as this

```
Message newMessage = parseNetworkResponse bla bla

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {          // 1
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        newMessage = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newMessage); // 2
        initialMessage.getNestedMessages().add(newMessage); // 3
    }
});                                                         // 4
```

There is no need for `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(initialMessage);`, since it will automatically be updated when you add an item to nestedMessages and commit that.

Also `RealmList<Message> nestedMessages = initialMessage.getNestedMessages();` is an unnecessary copy and requires more memory so I suggest you don't do that either.

Comment: isn't this the same as my answer?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori I have used this in my own code, I understand how it works and I am able to explain some things about it. You provided 2 snippets of code without any explanation at all, 1 of which you haven't tested and the other is incredibly unpractical. So no I do not think it's the same. OP is now probably using your 2nd code snippet because 'it works' even though it's not a good solution

Comment: My first solution is identical to your one, even if I didn't add an explanation to it. Editing my post or posting a comment as an explanation would to it too. Anyway gl further

Comment: @TimCastelijns please don't jump to conclusions about what the OP is doing.